# Git - Keep and ignore file changes before pulling from remote

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitignore, git-pull

I have a single file: `/creds.json` that I want to keep unchanged before I pull from a bitbucket remote and push to a github remote. I already have it in `.gitignore` and did `git update-index --skip-worktree creds.json` but the bitbucket branch shows changes made to the file and gets pulled to local and pushed to github regardless. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Make a backup version. After every pull, copy and paste the backup to overwrite the one in the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay Commit history will still show previous updates to that file.

Comment: @Daniel Harris, so you've checked in this file at some point and then later added it to `.gitignore`? Try `git update-index --assume-unchanged creds.json`. Note in doing this, if the file changes upstream, Git will fail if it needs to update this file in the index (i.e. a merge), so it must be resolved manually.